# Removing input when pressing button in Tkinter using python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

first time using Tkinter and I am trying to make a simple message system. The user puts in their message and name and presses the button to 'send it'. I want to clear the entry boxes ones the button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
    
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

window.title("NS Twitter")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Welcome!").pack()

label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Leave a message.").pack()

message = tkinter.Entry(window).pack()

label = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Put in your name.").pack()

name = tkinter.Entry(window).pack()

button = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Send.").pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The question: How do I clear the entry boxes ones the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. So start by "properly" declaring your widgets.

```
label1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Welcome!")
label1.pack()

label2 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Leave a message.")
label2.pack()

message = tkinter.Entry(window)
message.pack()

label3 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "Put in your name.")
label3.pack()

name = tkinter.Entry(window)
name.pack()

button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Send.")
button1.pack()
```

What this does is that it allows you to configure or later make some use of the entry widgets. Or else your variables will return `None` as the result of what is returned by `pack()`. To understand better, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/13382000). Also notice that I changed all the variables names to unique ones to avoid their repetition.

2. Now add a `command`(keyword argument) to your button:

```
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Send.",command=clear)
```

3. Now define the function `clear()`:

```
def clear():
    name.delete(0,'end')
    message.delete(0,'end')
```

Here, `delete(0,'end)` will remove everything in between the `0` index and the `end` of the respective entry widget. Also notice that you wont say `command=clear()` as this will call(invoke) the functions directly.

Also notice that saying `tkinter.Label()` and `tkinter.Entry()` can be tiresome to type at times, so I recommend to change your import statement to `import tkinter as tk`, so now you just have to say `tk.Label()` or `tk.Entry()` instead of the other longer ones.

So your final code would be:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def clear():
    name.delete(0,'end')
    message.delete(0,'end')

label1 = tk.Label(window, text = "Welcome!")
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(window, text = "Leave a message.")
label2.pack()

message = tk.Entry(window)
message.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(window, text = "Put in your name.")
label3.pack()

name = tk.Entry(window)
name.pack()

button1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Send.",command=clear)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

All these are just recommendations as you are just starting out tkinter and it is important to have a correct and better knowledge at the very beginning.